# Using static methods and fields how do I print math equations with answers?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a static class called Arithmetic with four static methods for basic arithmetic operation, namely: Add, Subtract, Multiply and Divide
Should produce the following result. Below is my syntax. Where am I going wrong?

```
1+1=2
2+2=4
3+3=6
4+4=8

4-2=2
8-4=4
16-8=8

4*2=8
8*4=32

4%2=2

No. Add=4
No. Subtract=3
No. Multiply=2
No. Divide=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is my syntax. Let me know what you think.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Arithmetic
    {
        public static int Add(int opreand1, int opreand2);
        public static int Subtract(int opreand1, int opreand2);
        public static int Multiply(int opreand1, int opreand2 );
        public static int Divide(int opreand1, int opreand2);
    }

        {
         return opreand1 + opreand2;
         return opreand1 - opreand2;
         return opreand1 * opreand2;
         return opreand1 / opreand2;

        }
    {

Console.WriteLine ("1+1={0}\r\n2+2={1}\r\n3+3={2}\r\n4+4={3}\r\n",  
                Arithmetic.Add (1, 1), Arithmetic.Add (2,2), Arithmetic.Add(3,3), 
                Arithmetic.Add(4,4));
Console.WriteLine("4-2={0}\r\n8-4={1}\r\n16-8={2}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Subtract(4, 2), Arithmetic.Subtract(8, 4), 
                Arithmetic.Subtract(16, 8));
Console.WriteLine("4*2={0}\r\n8*4={1}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Multiply(4, 2), Arithmetic.Multiply(8, 4));
Console.WriteLine("4%2={0}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Divide(4, 2));
Console.WriteLine("No. Add={0}\r\nNo. Subtract={1}\r\nNo. Multiply={2}\r\nNo. Divide={3}",
                Arithmetic.numAdd, Arithmetic.numSubtract, Arithmetic.numMutiply                           
                Arithmetic.numDivide);
 }
```

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a static class using C#, called Arithmetic with four static methods for basic arithmetic operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090115/how-to-write-a-static-class-using-c-called-arithmetic-with-four-static-methods)

Comment: The compiler will tell you *exactly* where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Try writing some compilable code first, and then ask a question that isn't a duplicate of the one you *already wrote*. It was closed for a reason (and you even got an answer!). Putting up code that doesn't even make sense, let alone compile, isn't going to inspire people to suddenly help.

Comment: You need to learn how to actually write basic C# before asking again.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer has the working code, here is an attempt at explaining what you did wrong:

1. You used a semicolon after your function declaration in the Arithmetic class. This basically indicates an empty function definition. The ONLY time this is an acceptable way to declare a function is if it is marked as `abstract` or is in an interface.
2. You then closed the Arithmetic class before your "function" definitions. This means that the subsequent code isn't part of the Arithmetic class.
3. Related to the above, you have two "functions" with no names, declaration, etc. They are just scopes put directly into the namespace. This won't compile since the only structures allowed at the namespace level are classes, enums, and structs.
4. Your arithmetic "function" is not contained in the Arithmetic class (noted above). It then has four return statements right in a row. Returning exits the function and returns program flow to the caller, meaning that the bottom three never run. Each function needs to be an actual separate function with declaration, body, etc.
5. The last Console.WriteLine references some properties or methods that don't exist in the arithmetic class. If they were supposed to be methods, there is no () after them so you are actually passing the delegate (type indeterminate since they are never declared) instead of the return value of the method.

I'm not trying to beat you up here, but this code is really, really bad. Please make sure you understand everything I wrote above, as well as why the code answer above works. Ask more questions here on SO or in the comments if you don't, because without understanding these fundamentals, you will have a very difficult time succeeding in writing C#.

Here is your code with comments next to the problems listed above.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Arithmetic
    {
        public static int Add(int opreand1, int opreand2);      //Closing semicolon means an empty function def
        public static int Subtract(int opreand1, int opreand2); //Same
        public static int Multiply(int opreand1, int opreand2 ); //Same
        public static int Divide(int opreand1, int opreand2); // Same
    } //This closing curly brace closed the class definition

        { //This opening curly brace doesn't make any sense, you are starting a new scope in the namespace, which isn't allowed.
         return opreand1 + opreand2; //Fine if this was the add function
         return opreand1 - opreand2; //Couldn't hit this line since you returned above
         return opreand1 * opreand2; //Same
         return opreand1 / opreand2; //Same

        } //Closed the undefined namespace-level scope
    { //Same as before, you are opening a scope in the namespace.

Console.WriteLine ("1+1={0}\r\n2+2={1}\r\n3+3={2}\r\n4+4={3}\r\n",  
                Arithmetic.Add (1, 1), Arithmetic.Add (2,2), Arithmetic.Add(3,3), 
                Arithmetic.Add(4,4));
Console.WriteLine("4-2={0}\r\n8-4={1}\r\n16-8={2}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Subtract(4, 2), Arithmetic.Subtract(8, 4), 
                Arithmetic.Subtract(16, 8));
Console.WriteLine("4*2={0}\r\n8*4={1}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Multiply(4, 2), Arithmetic.Multiply(8, 4));
Console.WriteLine("4%2={0}\r\n",
                Arithmetic.Divide(4, 2));
Console.WriteLine("No. Add={0}\r\nNo. Subtract={1}\r\nNo. Multiply={2}\r\nNo. Divide={3}",
                Arithmetic.numAdd, Arithmetic.numSubtract, Arithmetic.numMutiply                           
                Arithmetic.numDivide); //All these don't exist. If they are methods, you are passing the delegate, not the return of the method call.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I will review this!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Arithmetic
    {
        public static int Add(int opreand1, int opreand2)
        {
            return opreand1 + opreand2;
        }
        public static int Subtract(int opreand1, int opreand2)
        {
            return opreand1 - opreand2;
        }
        public static int Multiply(int opreand1, int opreand2 )
        {
            return opreand1 * opreand2;
        }
        public static int Divide(int opreand1, int opreand2)
        {
            return opreand1 / opreand2;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("1+1={0}\r\n2+2={1}\r\n3+3={2}\r\n4+4={3}\r\n",  
                        Arithmetic.Add(1, 1), Arithmetic.Add(2,2), Arithmetic.Add(3,3), 
                        Arithmetic.Add(4,4));
        Console.WriteLine("4-2={0}\r\n8-4={1}\r\n16-8={2}\r\n",
                        Arithmetic.Subtract(4, 2), Arithmetic.Subtract(8, 4), 
                        Arithmetic.Subtract(16, 8));
        Console.WriteLine("4*2={0}\r\n8*4={1}\r\n",
                        Arithmetic.Multiply(4, 2), Arithmetic.Multiply(8, 4));
        Console.WriteLine("4%2={0}\r\n",
                        Arithmetic.Divide(4, 2));
        Console.ReadKey(); // to keep the console open until you press a key
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, could you please add an explanation to what the OP had wrong? He clearly doesn't understand the basics of what he is trying to do and just giving him the program isn't going to help in the long run.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, and honestly I don't think you deserve one (you did answer the question after all). With an explanation, I would consider upvoting in fact. The downvote is likely more directed at the OP who posted a duplicate question with completely non-working code. Its not your fault.

Comment: Idc about points- just thought it was rude.  Glad it wasn't you.  Anyway, I think the code is an adequate explanation, but you are more than welcome to edit my answer and add anything helpful.  I appreciate your concern for the OP :)

Comment: Wrote an explanation referencing this code as correct (it was too major for an edit). I'll give you my vote for having the right answer, and because you didn't deserve the down vote :).